# Replacing spaces between sentences with double spaces

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

A client wants me to type up documents with double spaces between sentences, i.e.

```
Time is an illusion.  Lunchtime doubly so.
```

Rather than:

```
Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.
```

Is there a way to replace all of these single spaces with double spaces in a document? Replacing all instances of

```
". "
```

with

```
".  "
```

isn't ideal, as it will catch instances such as "I enjoy P.E. and biology."

Plus I need this to work for other punctuation, including exclamation marks, question marks, and sentences that end with a closing quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

> Choose Options from the Tools menu. Word displays the Options dialog
>   box. Make sure the Spelling & Grammar tab is displayed.
>
> Figure 1. The Spelling & Grammar tab of the Options dialog box. Click
>   on the Settings button. Word displays the Grammar Settings dialog box.
>
> Figure 2. The Grammar Settings dialog box. Use the Spaces Required
>   Between Sentences drop-down list to indicate how many spaces you
>   prefer between your sentences.
>
> Click on OK to close the Grammar Settings dialog box.
>
> Click on OK to close the Options dialog box.

[Source](http://word.tips.net/T001820_An_Automatic_Two_Spaces_after_a_Period.html)